# Buttons in collectionViewCell not triggering functions

Tags: swift, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell, swift5, addtarget

I created a button in a supplementary collectionView cell as header and added a button with a target to it but it doesn't trigger the function when tapped. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the button I created and its target function in the  cell class.

```
let dummyButton :UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("Dummy", for: .normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    button.layer.borderWidth = 1
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.brown
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTrash), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}() 


@objc func handleTrash (){
    print("It worked this time around so what was going on?")
}
```

I wrote all these in the collectionView Cell subclass. Please help

Comment: I created a supplementary view as header and added the button to the view

Comment: Solution found. I had to declare the buttons are lazy variables.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I had to declare the buttons as Lazy variables.

Answer (score 0):

Add the sender

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTrash(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func handleTrash (_ sender: UIButton){
    print("It worked this time around so what was going on?")
}
```